# Where does lein store Maven artefacts?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Where does lein store the various Jars it downloads from maven when I run:

```
lein deps
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do

```
lein classpath
```

The result will contain all the JARs that are available to your project.

On my machine, the Maven repository (that's where the JARs usually go), is at:

```
~/.m2/repository
```